# Cant solve a simple task in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a task.Here is the task:

The program creates a variable p with a value of 5, and a variable values with an empty array.

Complete the program with a loop that fills the array with values of p, where p is incremented by a random value between -0.5 and 0.5 at the end of each iteration (use Math.random() - 0.5).

Stop the loop when p is either negative or greater than 10.

And my code is:

```
  var p = 5;
  var values = [];

  while(p<10){
    p=p+(Math.random() - 0.5);
     values.push(p);
    p++;      
  }
 console.log(values);
```

But the online code editor says it's incorrect.And here is what it is saying: Error: You are missing 596 values in your array.
Who can help me? What is my mistake? Maybe using while loop is wrong way?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hint: You don't need the `p++`

Comment: can you inform us which code editor are you using because I tried reproducing in [see JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oyb180tc/)...It doesn't throw any error in console...

Comment: Can you please edit the short form of your question to at least remotely describe your problem?

Comment: ok, it's a edx course editor.And the course is EPFLx: NiC1.0x Nature, in Code: Biology in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed checking if `p<0`, otherwise the code is running fine, and `p++` was unnecessary unless as pointed by @Nkhangweni it just eliminates the possibility of an infinite loop.

```js
var p = 5;
var values = [];

while (p < 10 && p > 0) {
  p = p + (Math.random() - 0.5);
  values.push(p);
}
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  var p = 5;
  var values = [];

  while(p <10 && p > -10){
    p=p+(Math.random() - 0.5);
     values.push(p);
  }
 console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is the **code editor** you are using .
I run your code the was *no error* and **if p++ is removed then the loop will become a infinite loop.**

Comment: It might become an infinite loop, it will randomly go up or down over time.

Comment: I agree that adding p++ eliminates the possibility of `infinite loop`. But other than that I don't really find it useful.

Comment: It will contiune to go up

Comment: And reach ten then break

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = 5;
var values = [];

while (true) {
  p += (Math.random() - 0.5);

  if (p >= 0 && p <= 10) {
    values.push(p);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

console.log(values);
```

Comment: please add some description to answer for more help to questoner